Unity Integrated with Flutter App Closes When Switching Between Cameras on Android
I have an Android app integrated between Unity and Flutter. This app accesses the Android camera without issues, but recently I added the ability to switch between the front and rear cameras in the script (and in the UI).
As mentioned earlier, this app is made with Unity Engine and integrated with Flutter. In this case, it is possible to create a Unity (standalone) build for testing and also a (complete) build integrated with Flutter.
The behavior of switching between cameras occurs without problems when using the Unity (standalone) build in tests. However, when attempting the same camera switching in the Flutter-integrated build, the app closes unexpectedly. It doesn't matter if I start with the front or rear camera when launching the app; as soon as I try to switch cameras, the app crashes.
The Android logcat does not report any errors or exceptions.
Does anyone have any idea what might be happening, considering all these characteristics, or has anyone experienced something similar?
The camera switching should work normally in both the Unity (standalone) build and the Unity and Flutter integrated build. However, the integrated app experiences a sudden closure when attempting to switch between cameras.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.
